# Need help understanding why my Javascript variable is said to not be defined

Tags: javascript, dom

On the game I'm making [here](http://snakegamerecreation.org/), I have a bug I need to resolve and understand.

Repro steps:

1. Click on the above link.
2. Click `New Game`
3. Check JS console; see something like *"Uncaught ReferenceError: highSoreArr is not defined"*

I don't understand why this error is happening, because the sequence I have in my `head` is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Temporary hard-coded array for now; will be generated by server-side code later */
        var highScoreArr = [["Jon","130"], ["Michelle", "90"], ["Bob", "90"], ["Sally", "80"], ["Kurt", "10"]];
    </script>
    <script src="/scripts/snakescripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the error is in the included file, which should be read after `highScoreArr` is in existence -- right?

Comment: Somewhere in your script, you are missing a C.

Comment: voted to close for typographical error.

Comment: `var lowScore = parseInt(highSoreArr[0][1], 10);`

Comment: not to mention, the cheap name reference.  Steve Ballmer, really?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't have one of those hyper-intelligent Javascript interpreters that can tell instantly that `highSoreArr` and `highScoreArr` should refer to the same object :-)

For example, in your script:

```
var lowScore = parseInt(highSoreArr[0][1], 10);
                            ^^^
                       where is the c?
```

Comment: Wow, nearly 400k rep and you post an answer to an off-topic typo question?

Comment: Yes, because I'm mostly here to help. Even when the question gets closed as a typo, the OP will have still gotten their problem solved. Then it'll be up to the swarm whether the question is worthy to keep around (it probably isn't).

Comment: Which could easily have been pointed out in a comment.

Comment: You may do things how you wish. I will do things as I wish, subject to the rules of SO rather than the views of _one_ of its members.